# git : POST git-receive-pack

Tags: git

I am trying the below command to push the tag changes into the remote,

```
git config user.name "XXXXXX"
git config user.email "XXX@XXX.com"

$PAT = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`:$PAT"))


if (git tag -l | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -eq "test") { $_ } } ) {
# Deleting the tag
    git tag -d test; 
    git -c 'http.extraHeader=Authorization: Basic "XXXXXXXXXXXX="' push  -v origin --delete refs/tags/test 
}
#Adding the tag
git tag -a test -m "commit tag "
git push -v https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo refs/tags/test
```

but I am getting these errors

```
git : POST git-receive-pack (139 bytes)
At line:10 char:5
+     git -c 'http.extraHeader=Authorization: Basic "XXXXXXXXXX ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (POST git-receive-pack (139 bytes) 
   :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Pushing to https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo
To https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo
 - [deleted]         test


git : POST git-receive-pack (310 bytes)
At line:15 char:1
+ git push -v https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (POST git-receive-pack (310 bytes) 
   :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Pushing to https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo
To https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo
 * [new tag]         test -> test
```

**I have update my Git to latest version (git version 2.43.0.windows.1)**

I tried these commands,

```
git -c 'http.extraHeader=Authorization: Basic "XXXXXXXXXXXX="' push  -v origin refs/tags/test 
git push -v https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo refs/tags/test
git push origin refs/tags/tag-test
```